# Why its showing [object Object] when moving a html element via jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to move a html element inside a `menu div`, Its working and moving perfectly but its showing [object Object] not the `html anchor`.

[**My Fiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/rawat/Ltu2L7h1/)

**Html:**

```
 <div class="main">
    <a id="back">Back</a>
</div>
<div class="main menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
var back = $('#back');
var htmlBack = '<li>' + back + '</li>';
$('.menu > ul > li:first-child').before(htmlBack);
$('#back').closest('.main').remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
    var main = $('#back').parent();
    var htmlBack = $('#back').wrap('<li></li>').parent();
    $('.menu > ul > li:first-child').before(htmlBack);
    main.remove();
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltu2L7h1/15/)

Comment: thanks @alex the anchor tag just not only moving but also the parent of thag anchor tag removing, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Because you are taking `$('#back')` which is a jquery object, then concatinating it with string. 
You need to use `$("#back").text()` inorder to get its text.

OR you need to create an `li` first, then append the anchor element to it.

```
var back = $('#back');
var htmlBack = $("<li/>");
htmlBack.append(back);
$('.menu > ul > li:first-child').before(htmlBack);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltu2L7h1/8/)

Comment: then how can i do it.

Comment: yeah its working but i want to move anchor also, can u please again tell me how to perform it

Comment: but the closest div of #back with main class still remains,